# How do I create graphics for WebAssembly in C++14, that are implemented similarly to X11?

Tags: c++14, x11, webassembly

I'm currently working on building Chess in C++ for a school project. It's coming along really well, and I'm going to need to implement graphics pretty soon. Although I'm going to implement the graphics in X11, I was wondering how I might do it with WebAssembly, specifically which libraries are most similar to X11 that I could use. The GraphicsDisplay would just be an Observer to my Game class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot program in X11 with WebAssembly, you need graphics frameworks.

Currently the only GUI framework that officially support WebAssembly is Qt. Have a look at its [official documentation on WebAssembly](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.13/wasm.html). I recommend learning Qt Widgets in a common desktop environment (Linux, Windows, Mac...) then try to port it in WebAssembly.

The other way to implement graphics with WebAssembly is using frameworks for game. Emscripten (C/C++ to WebAssembly toolchain) has a strong support for OpenGL-based games. You probably want to look at [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/).